# CSS border will surround div but box shadow will not

Tags: css, sass, antd

I am customising and [Ant Design table](https://ant.design/components/table/) with scss and want to add a box shadow when hovering a table header cell. With the following code, the element is surrounded on each of the four sides of the element by a 1px green solid border, but the box shadow only ever shows up on the left hand side of the element, outside of it:

```css
  .ant-table-thead>tr>th:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px green !important;
    border: solid 1px green !important;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background: #E8F8F5;
    cursor: grab;
  }
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

How can I add the box shadow to every side of the element, inside and out? I have tried to make it work but I am missing something. TIA.

Comment: On the Ant page you linked to, adding `position: relative; z-index: 1;` to your CSS works. But without a [MRE] of your own code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Hi @Turnip thanks very much for the comment - with a positive `z-index` the box shadow now shows up on the right of the header cell as well. I've tracked the rest of the problem (top and bottom) down to `border-collapse` being `separate` and `border-spacing` being `0`, but apart from in the in chrome dev tools, I can't figure out how to overwrite that in my own css. If I toggle them both off it fixes it. Any idea how to approach that> I can't provide a minimal reproducible example I'm afraid

Comment: _"I can't provide a minimal reproducible example"_ Why? It is a requirement of this site. It doesn't have to be your real code if that is what you are worried about.

Comment: each example provides a codepen that you can copy/pasre code or fork or rebuild your case issue from : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOrYRdv ... and it shows that turnip advise works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try using an offset. For example:

```
box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px green
```

This should help.

Also, I'd not recommend using `!important` in your CSS, as it can cause problems.